# How to enable Kerberos Authentication Service auditing on 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, kerberos

I have a 2008-level Windows domain running 5 x 2008 (non-R2) DCs (it's on the roadmap to migrate to R2 or possibly 2012 in the next 9-12 months, but this project needs to be working first), and I need to enable Kerberos Authentication Service events in the Security event log for an AD-integrated web filtering system.

Apparently the "Kerberos Authentication Service" audit setting is new to 2008 R2 and not present in the 2008 GPO interface.

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772702%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) seems to indicate that I should be able to enable the setting on my "Default Domain Controller Policy" from a 2008 R2 member server and it would apply to 2008 servers:

> If this policy setting is configured, the following events are generated. The events appear on computers running Windows Server 2008 R2, ***Windows Server 2008***, Windows 7, or Windows Vista.
>
> Event ID   Event message
>
> 4768 A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested.
>
> 4771 Kerberos pre-authentication failed.
>
> 4772 A Kerberos authentication ticket request failed.

However, I've tried this and 4 of my 5 DCs apply the setting fine, but one of them isn't logging the audit events in the security logs.

Is there a better way to do this on a 2008 (non-R2) server?  Is there anything obvious that might be enabled (or disabled) on this oddball DC that's causing it not to accept the R2 setting?  Any other ideas of things to check?

I don't see anything unusual in the event logs on the offending DC.  Any ideas or help are appreciated.Thanks in advance for any assistance you all can offer.

***EDIT:*** Here is a link to [a previous question of mine](https://serverfault.com/questions/506426/2008-dc-gpo-advanced-audit-policy-configuration-missing/506433) where I asked how to enable this setting on Server 2008.  That question went stale, so I'm asking its next logical extension here.

Comment: I'm linking your previous question on this, as it may help clarify for the experts what you have already dealt with, you should include it as a link in your question as well.  http://serverfault.com/questions/506426/2008-dc-gpo-advanced-audit-policy-configuration-missing/506433#506433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still haven't been able to troubleshoot why these policy changes aren't being made on 1 of the 5 DCs, but I was able to work around this problem by running the following `auditpol` command on it:

```
auditpol /set /category:"account logon" /subcategory:"kerberos Authentication Service" /success:enable
```

After refreshing GP and rebooting the DC, the setting is still stuck, so I guess it's not being overwritten anywhere, so I'm calling this good.

Thanks to everyone who read this, and maybe it'll help others in similar situations.